# Creating a transparent text box in MATLAB GUI using GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

In a MATLAB GUI I have a picture in the background (created on axes) and over it I would like to have text. I put a static text box but I need it to be transparent. Can I do it using GUIDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use guide to do this, since the text objects are actually uicontrols. Try adding the text using the `text` function in your code instead. You may have to trial-and-error it in to the right location.