# How to set the background of a textbox with a color similar to an existing image background

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, textbox

I created text components as well as put a sort of background image in MatLab. What I wanted to do now is to set the background of the textbox the same as that of the image so as to make it a bit more pleasing). Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an image and some code, e.g. is it an edit-box you are using?

Comment: here's an image of it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hgyodttjxc6vn8/qqq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at least resolve the labeling-issue following [Creating a transparent text box in MATLAB GUI using GUIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604633/creating-a-transparent-text-box-in-matlab-gui-using-guide) and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/71098. The following code is provided by the latter link:

```
 imagesc(rand(128));
 colormap(hot(256));
 axis off;
 th=text;
 set(th,'units','normalized');
 set(th,'position',[.5 .5 0]);
 set(th,'horizontalalignment','center');
 set(th,'fontsize',32);
 set(th,'fontweight','bold');
 set(th,'color',[0 0 1]);
 set(th,'edgecolor',[1 1 1]);
 set(th,'string','this is a text box');
```

Regarding the dropdown-list, I'd assume you have to implement something yourself (e.g. using MouseDown-events).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS

CSS:

```
.txtbg{
background-image:url('images/bg.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="abc" class="txtbg">
```

Comment: How about in MatLab? I forgot to say I'm using MatLab.